# auto approve sharing request

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, share, auto-approve

**SP2013 on premise** here.

Users of a site should be allowed to share any document they have edit rights for.

While users can do this by the default behavior using an email sent to the owner of the site who needs to approve.

Is there some setting to **auto-approve** those requests?

We know that one can create a custom permission level including **manage permission** however then users have more privileges than they should.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use Work Flow to achieve the same. An impersonation step causes the actions within that step to run as the author of the workflow. So impersonation will also help author to auto approve document if not approved after some specific period of time.

You can use below link to implement the same.

[Workflow auto approve document](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159285/workflow-auto-approve-document)

Also you can take some help from below content type based auto approval link..

http://www.paulgrimley.com/2010/02/auto-approving-documents-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you know which event one could hook in here? Or do you mean to write an entire "share this" workflow from scratch?

Comment: If you have any existing workflow then you can extend the same or you need to create workflow from scratch. Any approach should work fine.